# Is it essential to remove NULL values when doing EDA?

Tags: data-analysis, missing-data

I'm doing a Data Analytics project on Youtube Statistics.

Assume that I want to get into the entertainment industry and decided to make a youtube channel. Before that, I need to identify what content I should focus on and how I'm gonna grow my channel. So I decided to do some research on the current trend/status of Youtube popular channels/videos and hoped to find some info or potentials. Somehow, I found useful data from different sources and gather them in a csv file.

**My ultimate goals are to explore the data and extract meaningful insights from it.**

But my dataset has too many rows that contain null values (almost like half of the dataset). Should I just remove those rows or perform some statistical/ML techniques to fill the values or just ignore them?

**Note:** this is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/152dYXdj1m7ZIGcTcM92mVlprqx1EUdXL/view?usp=drive_link) of the dataset. You can put some comments in the file if you wish

I really appreciate any solutions and opinions! Thanks!!!

Comment: MIssing data can have predictive value if they are correlated with the target variable, so be remember missing data is not always bad. On the other hand, if a significant percentage of data is missing that is just as bad as a significant number of values being the same in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

Like so many things, it’s going to depend on what you want to do with the data once it’s been cleaned. Your options include dropping the entire row where null values are present, dropping the columns that have null values, or setting the missing values to some precomputed value like mean, median, or zero.
A quick df.info of the dataset, and it looks like most of the null values are in attributes related to the country, population, etc., presumably of the YouTuber. Since you still have 872 valid values out of 995, you could probably drop these rows from your dataset, at least to start. The only other attribute you’d have to deal with is the subscribers for last 30 days. Here you have 658 valid values, so you could still drop nulls, or try to estimate the missing values from, say, video_views_for_the_last_30_days or some of the other columns.

```
|       |    rank |   subscribers |   video views |   uploads |   video_views_rank |   country_rank |   channel_type_rank |   video_views_for_the_last_30_days |   lowest_monthly_earnings |   highest_monthly_earnings |   lowest_yearly_earnings |   highest_yearly_earnings |   subscribers_for_last_30_days |   created_year |   created_date |   Gross tertiary education enrollment (%) |       Population |   Unemployment rate |   Urban_population |   Latitude |   Longitude |
|:------|--------:|--------------:|--------------:|----------:|-------------------:|---------------:|--------------------:|-----------------------------------:|--------------------------:|---------------------------:|-------------------------:|--------------------------:|-------------------------------:|---------------:|---------------:|------------------------------------------:|-----------------:|--------------------:|-------------------:|-----------:|------------:|
| count | 995     | 995           | 995           |    995    |      994           |        879     |             962     |                      939           |                     995   |              995           |               995        |             995           |                        658     |       990      |      990       |                                  872      |    872           |           872       |      872           |   872      |    872      |
| mean  | 498     |   2.29824e+07 |   1.10395e+10 |   9187.13 |   554249           |        386.053 |             745.719 |                        1.7561e+08  |                   36886.1 |           589808           |            442257        |               7.08181e+06 |                     349079     |      2012.63   |       15.7465  |                                   63.6278 |      4.30387e+08 |             9.27928 |        2.24215e+08 |    26.6328 |    -14.1281 |
| std   | 287.376 |   1.75261e+07 |   1.41108e+10 |  34151.4  |        1.36278e+06 |       1232.24  |            1944.39  |                        4.16378e+08 |                   71858.7 |                1.14862e+06 |            861216        |               1.3797e+07  |                     614355     |         4.5125 |        8.77752 |                                   26.1069 |      4.72795e+08 |             4.88835 |        1.54687e+08 |    20.5605 |     84.7608 |
| min   |   1     |   1.23e+07    |   0           |      0    |        1           |          1     |               1     |                        1           |                       0   |                0           |                 0        |               0           |                          1     |      1970      |        1       |                                    7.6    | 202506           |             0.75    |    35588           |   -38.4161 |   -172.105  |
| 25%   | 249.5   |   1.45e+07    |   4.28815e+09 |    194.5  |      323           |         11     |              27     |                        2.01375e+07 |                    2700   |            43500           |             32650        |          521750           |                     100000     |      2009      |        8       |                                   36.3    |      8.33554e+07 |             5.27    |        5.59083e+07 |    20.5937 |    -95.7129 |
| 50%   | 498     |   1.77e+07    |   7.76082e+09 |    729    |      915.5         |         51     |              65.5   |                        6.4085e+07  |                   13300   |           212700           |            159500        |               2.6e+06     |                     200000     |      2013      |       16       |                                   68      |      3.2824e+08  |             9.365   |        2.70663e+08 |    37.0902 |    -51.9253 |
| 75%   | 746.5   |   2.46e+07    |   1.35547e+10 |   2667.5  |     3584.5         |        123     |             139.75  |                        1.68826e+08 |                   37900   |           606800           |            455100        |               7.3e+06     |                     400000     |      2016      |       23       |                                   88.2    |      3.2824e+08  |            14.7     |        2.70663e+08 |    37.0902 |     78.9629 |
| max   | 995     |   2.45e+08    |   2.28e+11    | 301308    |        4.05794e+06 |       7741     |            7741     |                        6.589e+09   |                  850900   |                1.36e+07    |                 1.02e+07 |               1.634e+08   |                          8e+06 |      2022      |       31       |                                  113.1    |      1.39772e+09 |            14.72    |        8.42934e+08 |    61.9241 |    138.253  |
​
```